# How will Struts ActionForward redirect know if it has to redirect to http or https?

Tags: ssl, redirect, struts, struts-1

I am seeing mix content redirection error from https to http when I am doing new `ActionForward`. I am not able to figure out what `ActionForward` reads in order to determine that it has to go to http instead of https. I have old Struts v1.11.

Comment: Are you using `sslext` in your project?

Comment: No, but I may to resolve this issue, right now I am going route of changing server.xml of tomcat by adding remoteIpValve but if that fails then I will follow this route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ActionConfig` I suppose, but it's available via extension to Struts.

> An extension to version 1.1, named [`sslext`](http://sslext.sourceforge.net/), helps solve many of
>   the HTTP/HTTPS switching issues. It extends the `ActionConfig` class,
>   `RequestProcessor`, and Plugin classes to define a framework where
>   developers may specify the transmission protocol behavior for Struts
>   applications. Within the Struts configuration file, developers specify
>   which action requests require HTTPS transmission and which should use
>   HTTP. Developers can also specify whether to redirect
>   "improperly-protocoled" requests to the correct protocol.
>
> In addition to these extensions, the `<html:link>` and the
>   `<html:form>` tags have been extended. In these extensions, the Struts
>   actions specified in either of these tags are analyzed to determine
>   the protocol that should be used in requesting that action. The HTML
>   generated by these tags will specify the proper protocol. An
>   additional custom tag is defined for allowing users to specify the
>   transmission protocol for an individual JSP. This is most often used
>   for form-based authentication pages.

Comment: I will mark this as answer since it seems like pointing towards what I was looking for. I ended up solving this issue using remoteIpValve in tomcat server.xml.

Comment: @jarus Welcome to StackOverflow! Feel free to add your own answer to the question if you have a better solution to the problem.