# How does ActionForward constructs the URL with Prototype (http/https)?

Tags: ssl, struts, redirect

This is in continuation of the question asked in;

> [How will Struts ActionForward redirect know if it has to redirect to http or https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127354/how-will-struts-actionforward-redirect-know-if-it-has-to-redirect-to-http-or-htt)

I am seeing mix content redirection error from https to http when I am doing new `ActionForward`. I am not able to figure out what `ActionForward` reads in order to determine that it has to go to http instead of https. I have old Struts v1.11.
Can you please give some code example how it is done?

I am also facing an issue where `ActionForward` is redirecting to http, but i wanted to get to https.
All we are passing in `ActionForward` is the relative path and the boolean value of redirect which is true. 
I am wondering how the complete URL along with the protocol is getting generated.

Comment: Before asking for code show us that you understand the question.

Comment: This is not the continuation of the previous question. It's the same question. Voting to close.